# Switching RS485

Tags: arduino, rs485, dpdt

I'm using RS485 on an Arduino with a MAX485. The comms goes out to a two core loom, but I need to use the same loom for two purposes (non simultaneously):

1. Provide power to a device
2. RS485 communication to a sensor

The problem is I need to use the same loom for both, but not simultaneously. So realistically I could just use a DPDT switch with power and the comms input and the two-core cable as an output. But is there anyway to do it logically? Maybe run the power and comms in through a relay and out to the loom and switch it with the Arduino? Or maybe a couple of transistors?

I'm relatively new with RS485 so I'm not sure if that will cause to much noise or if it will be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "a two core loom"?

Comment: RS485 really does need a ground wire as well as A and B.

Comment: I've posted fairly generic answer. But if you can provide more details you may get better suggestions. Specifically: 1) is your communication bidirectional or unidirectional, 2) baud rate, 3) minimal power supply voltage for the sensor (assuming "sensor" and "device" are the same, it is not clear from the question)

Answer (score 0):

There are electrical switches, usually called analog switches or analog multiplexers, which indeed use a couple of transistors (a  [transmission gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate) consists of two MOSFETs).

You have to choose a 2-channel 2:1 switch that supports all the voltages and currents that can occur in your application. (Many signal switches are not optimized for a very low resistance, which can be problematic for a power line.)

Comment: oh that might work! here's a quick schematic of what I want to do:                              [link](https://freeimage.host/i/H4zQ541) _italic_ **bold**                                                            basically it will be disconnected from the sensor when switched over to 5v and then I can just use a multi meter to check continuity at the sensor end. so would a transmission gate work for this?

Answer (score 0):

As @Andyaka pointed out in the comments, RS-485 does require ground wire to make sure common-mode of the bus stays in the specified range for the transceivers.

So, the simplest solution would be to change the wiring to 4 conductors (at least one twisted pair) and use two of them for power. Common approach is to have higher voltage and tiny PoL modules sized just enough for local loads.

However if there is no way to change the wiring you can consider capacitive coupling of the transceivers with DC-carrying bus. TI has pretty good reference design [TIDA-00527](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00527) specifically for RS-485. It has an obvious limitation in that it can't carry any low-frequency or DC content, so whether or not you can use it depends on sensor's protocol.

Another option is to use isolated transceivers with built-in power converters. Not a bullet-proof solution without at least a floating common ground, but much more reliable than what you have now.

Finally, if sensor protocol makes it impossible to use capacitive coupling and you still limited by 2-conductor wiring then you may have to rethink the physical layer of your connection. After all, MAX485 uses UART on the data link layer, same as many others PHY devices. If your sensors do not require high bandwidth of RS-485 you may find PHY more suitable for power delivery.

For example, if your communication is unidirectional, you may be able to use standard 4-20mA current loop receiver/transmitter. Even though they are designed for analog signals, they should be OK for low-bandwidth digital communication. And their transmitters (e.g. [XTR117](https://www.ti.com/product/XTR117)) have regulated power output for sensors.

Comment: MAX485, or RS485 in general, does not have to use UART and the sensor may not use it. The assumption that it does is valid as most devices do, but for example RS422/RS485 are used for other interfaces with other protocols such as AES digital audio or DisplayPort AUX channel.

Comment: @Justme yes, of course. As I pointed out in the comments, this is quite generic answer to the very generic question. If OP can fill in the blanks the assumptions can change or go away altogether.